# App termination segue?

Tags: iphone, segue, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard app with about 10 veiw controllers and one login view controller, How can i segue to the login view (which is set as the initial view) from any of the 10 views once the app is closed or terminated? Thanks

Comment: You mean data permanently stored ?

Comment: [Le Documentation, monsieur?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: @mattsaravitz You should revise your question. You want to know how to do this when the app is backgrounded. The app does not terminate when someone hits the home button or switches apps, which is what I think you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Editing and starting over. I miss understood the question.

You have two options

**Option 1**: Change the view when you enter the foreground. Here is an example of reloading the storyboard

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
```

**Option 2**: Reload your hole app when someone leaves

In the info plist set **"Application does not run in background"** to **YES**

In xCode you can get to this by selecting the project on the left, the target, and then the info tab

Comment: Thanks, but i just changed the application does not run in background plist option to true, works great.

Comment: @mattsaravitz I was very confused by that, until I re-read the question. I updated my answer now that I better understand the question.